# Как после каждой 3-й строки вставить символ?

Tags: python

У меня есть большой файл в нём идёт текст формата

- Anya
- 23
- female

Как мне после каждых 3-х строк (4-ой строкой) записать свой символ или слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно прибегнуть к обыкновенному счетчику

```py
buffer = ""
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        buffer += line
        i+=1
        if i == 3:
            i = 0
            buffer += userword
with open(wfilename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Простое решение читать из файла, писать прочитанное во временный файл или в память. По завершении операции перезаписать файл.